# use direct oauth with google facebook and linkedIn or with a third party like hybridAuth

Tags: php, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, hybridauth

I've been trying to integrate in my web app, sign in and sign up with facebook google and linkedin by following their documentation but Didn't workout for me so I tried to do it with hybridAuth .My question is first of all is it as safe as using them directly? and secondly how to verify if the user exist in my DB by using hybrithauth before authentication?.

Comment: Better to solve why the normal route didn't work for you, IMO, it should work unless you have some very odd scenario

Comment: Then again a 3rd party library might make it easier in some ways. But we can't really answer about "safety" because a) that's rather a vague term and needs a more specific definition about what exactly you're concerned about (and why) and b) we're not security researchers.

Comment: it is hard to integrate specially with linkedIn and I don't know how to check the email and psw with my existing db before proceeding with the auth or the sign up. if you have any good exemple or documentation plz share it .

Comment: Also are you using PHP or node? Not sure why you've tagged both

Comment: Asking for documentation and tutorials is specifically off-topic here, sorry. It's not our job to do your googling for you. Https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I am using php for front and nodejs for backEnd

Comment: PHP is a server side language so that doesn't make any sense. PHP and node are both backend tools. Do you mean you have a web app written in html with PHP on the server, and then an API as well using node? Not really clear, although it's hard to say, from the minimal details, whether it's relevant to the question or not

Comment: `I don't know how to check the email and psw with my existing db`...if you're using a 3rd party login then the password wouldn't be stored in your database...that's the whole point of these kind of integrations, you don't deal with the user's credentials directly - that is all handled by Facebook/LinkedIn/whoever, and your app just gets a token back to say who the user is and that they authenticated correctly.